# Feel the difference between words

Tags: word-difference, word-in-context

I am trying to feel the difference between these words: **vacant**, **unoccupied**, **spare** and **free**.

If we are talking about locations that aren't controlled by military forces then which of the above words do we use? What word could mean, "**available to be freely taken by army forces without intrusion**"?

Comment: **Vacant** does not mean "available to be taken"  even though a vacant hotel room is one that can be made available to a guest who wants a room. **Vacant** means "unoccupied" or "empty".  An army **vacates** a position, which then becomes **vacated**.

Comment: You'd be as likely to say the "landmark" (whatever that might mean) was ***undefended***. But we'd need a *very* complete context to rule on whether any of *vacant, unoccupied, spare, free* might be credible usages, and even if you could provide that context, I think any answers would be POB

Comment: I've edited the question for it to be better understood.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The adjective **vacant** simply means "empty", not "*left* empty".  To express the idea of "left empty" (and thus, in your example, left unguarded) you need to use the past participle adjectivally, which, with transitive verbs, expresses the idea of "in-the-state-an-agent-put-it-in".

> The place had been vacated by the army, and was therefore vulnerable.
>
> Vacated, the place was vulnerable to being taken over by hostile forces.

A vacant room might never have been occupied. A vacated room has had people in it.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in comments, "undefended" works better than any of the proposals in your question text.

However, I feel unguarded works best. Somehow undefended is a harder word to say quickly.